# Find element by HTML in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I've started implementing *Cypress* for some regression tests, and I'm trying to find a particular element in a list of elements. The elements are in this format:

```
<div class="navigationIcon">
    <input>
    <div>
        <img class="navigationImage" src="[image/path]">
        <div class="navigationText">[navigation text]</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On a single page, there are several of these. I'd like to try and target a specific on by the [navigation text], but it is possible for them to have similar text. My main example is one with "Profiles" and a second one with "Membership Profiles". So, doing `cy.contains("Profiles")` will give me the "Membership Profiles" element instead of "Profiles".

Please keep in mind, this is used in a function, like this:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('goTo', (places) =>
{
    // Navigate to the places
});
```

Where "places" is an array of pages to navigate to. So, I don't know the exact text I'm looking for in the function to say something like `and !text === 'Membership Profiles'`.

Does anyone know how I can grab the elements by the html content? This is the function I came up with:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('goTo', (places) =>
{
    for (let i = 0; i < places.length; i++)
    {
        let place = places[i];
        let navLinks = Cypress.$('.navigationIcon').toArray();
        navLinks.some((link) =>
        {
            if (link.innerHTML.includes(`>${place.name}</div>`))
            {
                cy.wrap(link).click();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

but this is moving onto the next outer for loop iteration too fast and the second time through the `navLinks` variable pulls the same elements from the previous iteration.

Does Cypress have something built in to let me search by HTML? I've been looking around the documentation, but I can't find anything.

Comment: you should give your html data-attributes so that they're more static and less likely to change for example  data-name-it="navigiation-icon" then grab them with cy.get('[data-name-it=navigiation-icon')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with this, I haven't tested it but I believe it will do what you're after.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('goTo', place => {
  cy.get("div.navigationIcon > div > div").then($navs => {
    var $desiredNav = $navs.find($nav => {
      return $nav.text() == place;
    });

    cy.wrap($desiredNav).click();
});
```

To make it work with your places array, I'd do this, or the for loop could be placed in your tests:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('goToPlaces', places => {
  for (let i = 0; i < places.length; i++)
  {
    cy.goTo(places[i]);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that! While it didn't work out of the box, I was able to mess with it and get it to do what I needed. I posted my final solution in a separate answer, but I'm accepting yours since it's mostly your code. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Brendan's answer, I was able to get something working:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('navigateTo', (places) =>
{
    for (let i = 0; i < places.length; i++)
    {
        cy.goTo(places[i]);
    }
});

Cypress.Commands.add('goTo', (place) =>
{
    cy.log(`Navigating to ${place.name}`);

    cy.get('div.navigationIcon > div > div').then(($navLinks) =>
    {
        for (let i = 0; i < $navLinks.length; i++)
        {
            let $link = Cypress.$($navLinks[i]);
            if ($link.text().trim() === place.name)
            {
                // Click the link
                cy.wrap($link).click();
                break;
            }
        }

        // Ensure the url changed
        cy.url().should('include', place.uri);
    });
});
```

Note:

I pass in an array to the `navigateTo` function, like this:

```
cy.navigateTo([
    { name: 'Setup', uri: '#Setup:'},
    { name: 'Profiles', uri: '#Profiles:'},
    { name: 'Addresses', uri: '#Addresses:'}
]);
```

So that it'll navigate to the page, and then validate the move via the URL

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

`cy.get('.navigationIcon .navigationText:contains("[navigation text]")')`